# Equation with cases

Tags: cases

How to typeset this equation?

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \text{simult\'aneas:}
    \quad
    \begin{cases}
    2x+y=3\\
    2x-y=1\\
    \end{cases}
    \quad
    \Leftrightarrow
    \quad
    x=1,~y=1
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
    \text{simult\'aneas:}
    \quad
    \begin{cases}
    2x+y=3\\
    2x-y=1\\
    \end{cases}
    \quad
    \Leftrightarrow
    \quad
    x=y=1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \text{simult\'aneas:}
    \quad
    \begin{cases}
    2x+y=3\\
    2x-y=1\\
    \end{cases}
    \quad
    \Leftrightarrow
    \quad
    \begin{cases}
    x=1\\
    y=1\\
\end{cases}\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to change `\text` to `\textsf`.

This might be considered a beginner's question, so you might want to have a look on [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner/105#105).

Comment: this is really a one-line display, so `equation*` would be more appropriate than `align*`.